# Inverse of function $y = x * e^{(x-1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Trying to rewrite the function: $$y = x * e^{(x-1)}$$

to: $$x = …$$

Another way to write it is:$$ln(y) + 1 = ln(x) + x$$

I can't find a way to get a non-logarithmic or non-exponential x.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think you can actually find an analytic expression..

Comment: What you are looking for is related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lambert W function is defined as the inverse of $y=xe^x$ that is $W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$ and $W(xe^x)=x$. So you can solve in terms of it

$$
\begin{split}
y &= xe^{x-1}\\
ey &= xe^x\\
W(ey)&=x
\end{split}
$$

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function